# Index not found exception on deleting unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have an ES cluster where pods are failing from time to time.

I checked out cluster health and noticed that there were too many unassigned shards in my cluster

```
{
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"status" : "red",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 5,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
"active_primary_shards" : 274,
"active_shards" : 274,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 8,
"unassigned_shards" : 8568,
"delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks" : 16,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 56344,
"active_shards_percent_as_number" : 3.096045197740113
```

}

I tried deleting the unassigned shards using the command

```
curl -X GET 'elasticsearch-qna:9200/_cat/shards?pretty' | grep UNASSIGNED | awk {'print $1'} | xargs -i curl -XDELETE 'elasticsearch-qna:9200/{}'
```

However, got Index Not Found Exception when trying to delete of the form.

```
{
"acknowledged" : true
}
{
"error" : {
  "root_cause" : [
    {
      "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
      "reason" : "no such index",
      "index_uuid" : "_na_",
      "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
      "resource.id" : "ResourceID",
    "index" : "en-data-service"
  }
],
"type" : "index_not_found_exception",
"reason" : "no such index",
"index_uuid" : "_na_",
"resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
"resource.id" : "NA",
"index" : "en-data-service"
},
"status" : 404
}
```

Removed the resource ID and index from the JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using xargs. 
please use this solution and let me know if it works.

```
curl -X GET 'elasticsearch-qna:9200/_cat/indices?pretty' | grep -i red | awk 'print $3'> indices-for-delete

for i in `cat indices-for-delete` ; do echo $i ; curl -XDELETE 'elasticsearch-qna:9200/$i' ; done
```

note that I change _cat/shards to _cat/indices and trying to find red indices not unassigned shard. because of there maybe unassigned shard due to unallocated replicas.

Comment: please delete an index and check if it is not deleted?